# android+ffmpeg:Every seconds add different text to video

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

[add time to video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu3Wl.jpg)

```
ffmpeg -i d:/ffmpeg/old.mp4 -y -r 1 -i d:/ffmpeg/times/everysecond%05d.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=200:y=0" -vcodec mpeg4 d:/ffmpeg/out.mp4
```

this command run on windows ok,but run on android application finished

Comment: It has been bothering me for a week.

Comment: Show the (full) console output from Android.

Comment: @Mulvya,only this one LogCat: 08-19 08:55:50.059: A/libc(8689): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x4 in tid 8689 (droidtranscoder)

Comment: Suggest upgrading ffmpeg version.